# How is calculated the "lowest hash value" in Proof-of-stake random block selection?

Tags: proof-of-stake, hash, validators

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/proof-of-stake-pos-in-blockchain/
Dont know how you can get the "lowest hash value". Hash value in PoW I can understand, is it related? How does it work in PoS?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is perfectly legitimate, and the link you provide doesn't do a good job of explaining what it means.

I am not sure, but I think they refer to how Algorand determines the block proposer. In their case, there is randomness linked to a value not temperable by validators. The hash of some predefined value (such as the height of the block + the validator public key) must be smaller than a specific number for the validator to actually be allowed to propose a block.

But this is a particular case and not all PoS randomness work in this fashion at all. A thorough explanation of Ethereum randomness is given [here](https://nodeguardians.io/dev-hub/quests/consensus-randao).